# chained dropdown from database

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

so basically im trying to achieve this: When someone selects any option from the drop down called subject, the sections drop down should show all sections of that subject. The subject drop down works well, fetches all names of subjects but the sections one won't work. Im unable to find the issue. Thanks in advance. My code is below:

my js code

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
function getSection(strURL)
{      
alert(strURL);   
 var req = getXMLHTTP(); // fuction to get xmlhttp object
 if (req)
 {
  req.onreadystatechange = function()
 {
  if (req.readyState == 4) { //data is retrieved from server
   if (req.status == 200) { // which reprents ok status                    
     document.getElementById('sectiondiv').innerHTML=req.responseText;
  }
  else
  { 
     alert("There was a problem while using XMLHTTP:\n");
  }
  }            
  }        
req.open("GET", strURL, true); //open url using get method
req.send(null);
 }
}
</script>
```

php code:

```
<div>
            Subject:

    <?php

    $conn = new mysqli('localhost', '', '', '') 
    or die ('Cannot connect to db');

        $result = $conn->query("select name from class");


        echo "<select name='subject' onchange='getSection('findsection.php?subject=>'this.value'";

        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

                      unset($id, $name);
                      $name = $row['name']; 
                      echo '<option value="subject">'.$name.'</option>';

    }

        echo "</select>";
    ?> 
            </div>
    <br>  
    <div id="sectiondiv">
    Section: 
        <select name="select">
     </select>
            </div>
```

my findsection.php

```
<? $subject=intval($_GET[‘subject’]);;
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "";
$password = "";
$dbname = "";
$mysqli  = new Mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname) or mysqli_error($mysqli);
$section = $mysqli->query("SELECT section FROM class WHERE name = '$subject'")->fetch_object()->section; 
$result=mysql_query($section);?>
<select name="section">
<? while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) { ?>
   <option value><?=$row['section']?></option>
<? } ?>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "<select name='subject' onchange='getSection('findsection.php?subject=>'this.value'";
```

You appear to be missing a bracket here.

I sincerely hope it's that simple, lemme know! :D

Comment: no that didnt solve anything, it was a mistake when i copied/pasted.